# Get a document from firebase and access the data returned by the function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a document from my firebase database, but I cannot access the generated data, I can only see it in the console

**at service:**

```
getOrderStat(){
   var docRef = this.db.collection("orders").doc("--stats--");
   return docRef.get().toPromise().then(doc => {
   this.ordern = doc.data().ordern
   console.log(this.ordern);

}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
})
```

**in my component.ts**

console.log(this.orderService.ordern)
outside the function the variable is displayed undefined

please I need to retrieve that data in a variable and then print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value inside `then` but you are accessing it before it sets.
you need to change like below

```
getOrderStat(){
   return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var docRef = this.db.collection("orders").doc("--stats--");
     docRef.get().toPromise()
       .then(doc => {
           const ordern = doc.data().ordern
           console.log(ordern);
           resolve(ordern);
        }).catch(function(error) {
           console.log("Error getting document:", error);
           reject(err);
        })
   })
}
```

then when you want to use it do like

```
  async useValue() {
    const ordern = await service.getOrderStat();
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, very grateful, Your answer was precise and correct. Now my code is working and I can use the data read